# manipulating earphone jack output

Tags: java, android, audio

I was wondering if there is anyway I can send an output to the left or right earphone separately in terms of a frequency that will generate a buzz. My main motive is that by the press of either the left arrow button, or the right, the respective earbud (left or right) will generate a buzzing sound. Can anyone please help. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I know C/C++ can do this, since I had an acquaintance who was a speech and hearing clinician, and he needed a C/C++ programmer for his research.

Comment: What platform/language are you working on?

Comment: I am working with the Java for Android language. I am trying to run this program on an android phone. Thanks for the insight, please post more. I am in need of help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this that would be portable across different platforms would be to just generate stereo audio where the audio is only on the left or right channel, i.e. set all the sample values for the unwanted channel to 0. That way you don't need to worry about manipulating the audio APIs or output hardware on any given platform.